# Why won't my Silverlight PivotViewer load?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, pivotviewer

I have a PivotViewer app I am working on, but, I cannot get it to run.

I have a good .cxml file (I used Pauthor to generate the related deep-zoom files).  I have tried running it from inside VS 2010 int debug and even built it and tried running it from my localhost. I've checked it in both Firefox and IE. I've made sure it is in a container with set width and height. I've made sure I have the most current silverlight.js, I've set the appropriate MIMEs on IIS.

My XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="DomPivot.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:pivot="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Pivot;assembly=System.Windows.Pivot"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="400" Height="400">
        <pivot:PivotViewer x:Name="myPivot" Height="350"></pivot:PivotViewer>
      </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

My error:

```
    Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception. [Line: 11 Position: 52]   
    at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
    at DominionPivot.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
    at DominionPivot.MainPage..ctor()
    at DominionPivot.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
    at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Source File: DomPivotTestPage.aspx
Line: 0

Line 11 Position 52 of the main.xaml is now the equal sign for the Height property of the pivotviewer. Interesting that BEFORE I added the height property, the project threw this error at the equal sign for the x:Name property.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error and would appreciate some help. I've investigated the other topics here but none of those answers either worked or pertained to my situation.

UPDATE:

I've attempted to make sure it isn't some kind of other error cascading into an inability for the control to load by attempting to load a .CXML file from a public source. Same result. I don't think the control itself is loading, so, I can't even debug the code that loads the collection.

Googling "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception." is no help. It returns 24 hits. Half of those are unrelated. The other half is another person with what appears to be the same problem posting to half-dozen or more forums and getting no answer either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK....so here are a number of issues that a lot of frustrating googling and futzing revealed:

```
 Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
```

I'm not entirely sure how this parameter ended up in my UserControl tag, but, it is unnecessary and eliminated the error referenced in my question.

I also moved the LoadCollection method out of its own event and into the UserControl_Loaded event and got things to progress.

Next I found that if you are using Visual Studio to run the project, make sure you specify the port number both in your code and in your web project settings. These obviously need to be changed when you post to a live server.

Lastly, I was led to believe that you HAD to use either the freely available Pauthor tools or the Excel plug-in to transform your collection into a Deep Zoom. Which also requires futzing with IIS to allow .dzi and .dzc.

Not so. There is a freely available Microsoft Deep Zoom Composer tool. In that tool you can compose your deep zoom and export the collection. You'll end up with several xml files and image folders. I found that all you have to do is then reference the output_dzc.xml file in your collection.cxml as your ImgBase and make sure your IDs match between the two files. That's all.

I hope this saves someone the frustration I've experienced the last few weeks trying to use this awesome but pathetically under-documented control.

I would also recommend this blog entry:

http://indiandotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/pivot-viewer-example-cricket-world-cup-2011/

It contains a link to a very simple pivotviewer VS 2010 solution file you can use to examine and familiarize yourself with file and directory structure as well as the necessary XML file structure and solution settings.